# How does an MSI determine which website to delete on uninstallation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, wix3.5

I've recently run into the following scenario:

1. Install an msi package created through WiX, which deploys files and creates + configures a website in IIS (6)
2. The website is manually modified. The port is changed from 81 to 80.
3. The package is uninstalled.

When the package is uninstalled, the website that is deleted is NOT the one which was deployed. Instead, I've seen it delete the Default Website, as well as some other ones.

What I would like to know is, how does the package determine which website to remove? It apparently isn't the IIS ID like I originally thought.

Comment: I had a similar issue and my solution was to store the website name in the registry and use a registry search to get the value and store it in a property. If the package is uninstalled, the website is removed properly.

Comment: If going by the registry, wouldn't it be better to store the website's ID? or is this not feasible if you're letting IIS decide the ID of your website?

Comment: That's correct, I'm storing both the ID and the virtual directory name, but Wix is using the ID to install / uninstall. Here is the element used by Wix:
`<iis:WebSite Id="WebSite" Description="Default" SiteId="[WIXCUSTOM_IIS_WEBSITE]">`
where `[WIXCUSTOM_IIS_WEBSITE]` is the property storing the web site id.

Answer (score 0):

We did it via registry keys:

```
    <Property Id="INBOUNDGATEWAY_REGPATH" Value="SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyApp\$(var.VERSION)\InboundGateway" />

    <Property Id="INSTALLEDWEBSITE">
        <RegistrySearch Id="INSTALLEDWEBSITE" Root="HKLM" Key="[INBOUNDGATEWAY_REGPATH]" Name="WebSite" Type="raw" />
    </Property>

    <iis:WebSite Id='MyWebSite' SiteId='*' Description='[WEBSITENAME]' Directory='FOLDER_VDIR'>
        <iis:WebAddress Id='WebSiteAddress' Port='[WEBPORT]'/>
    </iis:WebSite>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    ...
                        <Component Id="CPNT_INBOUNDGATEWAY_REGISTRY" Guid="etc..." DiskId="1">
                            <RegistryValue Id="INBOUNDGATEWAY_REGISTRY_WEBSITE" Type="string" Root="HKLM" Key="[INBOUNDGATEWAY_REGPATH]" Name="WebSite" Value="[WEBSITENAME]">
                                <Permission User="[LOCADMINSGROUP]" GenericAll="yes" />
                                <Permission User="[POOL_IDENTITY_USER]" Read="yes" GenericRead="yes" />
                            </RegistryValue>

    <CustomAction Id="SetToInstalledWebSite" Property="WEBSITENAME" Value="[INSTALLEDWEBSITE]" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="SetToInstalledWebSite" After="SetWEBSITENAME">Installed And INSTALLEDWEBSITE</Custom>
```